# How to read part of a TIFF as array and export it with its correct coordinates using GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, array

I would  like to be able to read a part of a TIFF file as a numpy array (using read as array(xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize) and be able to export it again to TIFF file, having this subset its correct coordinates. I was thinking obtaining the Geotransform from the original file, and adding/substracting from its coordinates, the offsets multiplied by the pixel size. I think that would give me the correct Geotransform to apply it when exporting. Would that be correct? Would there be any other way? (I dont want to use gdal_translate for this process).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will work as long as your images aren't rotated, i.e. `gt[2] == gt[4] == 0`.  Have a look at rasterio if you're not tied to straight-up gdal:  https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html#data-windows

Comment: In my case they are projected images with no rotation. I didnt know what those numbers (gt[2] == gt[4]) were. Where can I read about what the values of the GeoTransform tuple mean? Thx

Comment: Those are the x and y rotation coefficients.  See here:  https://www.gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html#gdal_datamodel_dataset_gtm

Comment: More info can be read from http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?pid=3034&topicname=World_files_for_raster_datasets - a GDAL GeoTransform object is similar to the values in a world file (slightly different order) https://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html and search for adfGeoTransform. there are some comments there that might help.